# How to properly make an entry widget have a placeholder when the show parameter is used in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a place holder class that takes two parameters, a tkinter entry and the text of the entry, or the place holder. Initially, the entry is configured to show "•". When I use the place holder class, instead of the entry showing the place holder, the characters appear as "•". I don't know how to fix this and any help would be highly appreciated.

Below is my class.

```
from tkinter import *   
class Place_Holder:
    def __init__(self,entry,place_holder):
        self.place_holder=place_holder
        self.entry=entry
        self.entry.bind("<FocusIn>",self.focus_in)
        self.entry.bind("<FocusOut>",self.focus_out)
        self.put_text(self.place_holder)
    def put_text(self,place_holder):
        self.entry.insert(0,place_holder)
        self.entry["fg"]="gray"
    def focus_in(self,event=0):
        if self.entry["fg"]=="gray":
            self.entry.delete(0,END)
            self.entry["fg"]="black"
    def focus_out(self,event=0):
        if not self.entry.get():
            self.entry.delete(0,END)
            self.put_text(self.place_holder)
```

And the following code is how I tried to test it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
def main():
    global root
    root=Tk()
    testing()
    root.mainloop()
def testing():
    global frame,variable,entry2
    frame=Frame(root)
    frame.grid()
    variable=IntVar()

    label=Label(frame,text="Username:")
    label.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)

    entry=Entry(frame,width=20)
    entry.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)
    entry.focus()


    label2=Label(frame,text="Password:")
    label2.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

    entry2=Entry(frame,width=20,show="•")
    entry2.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)

    check_but=ttk.Checkbutton(frame,text="Show Password",variable=variable,command=switch)
    check_but.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)

    entry1_config=Place_Holder(entry,"Username")
    entry2_config=Place_Holder(entry2,"Password")
def switch():
    if variable.get()!=1:
        entry2.configure(show="")
    else:
        entry2.configure(show="•")      
main()
```

Comment: It shows "•" because you configured it to show that.

Comment: Unset the `show` attribute when you display the placeholder.

Comment: @Artemis Fowl. The point is to show the "•", because it is a password entry.@Bryan Oakley. I tried doing entry2.configure(show="•") after I used the placeholder class but didn't work either.

Comment: @BryanOakley Did you get pinged for above comment? I thought you could only ping one person other than the post owner per comment. (sorry this is slightly irrelevant, I'll probably delete it after)